# Anyone having a GSM module please confirm. Is it normal to have the terminals of SIM800L EVB antenna shorted?

Tags: signal, gsm, troubleshooting, module

My SIM800L-EVB GSM module wasn't registering to network even after providing good power supplies. On troubleshooting I found that the terminals A and B, to which the antenna attaches(see img attached) are shorted. Is the product damaged or is it normal?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> *On troubleshooting I found that the terminals A and B, to which the
> antenna attaches(see img attached) are shorted.*

It may register as being shorted at DC on a multimeter but, this is likely because there is an antenna matching inductor to ground. Of course, at the real operating frequencies of your antenna that inductance won't be a short circuit.

> *Is the product damaged or is it normal?*

Benefit of the doubt is that the product is not damaged but, there's nothing else to substantiate this other than my gut feeling. If you can find a schematic, that would help.

Comment: Sir I removed the antenna while checking... also the terminals of antenna are not giving a DC short.  Did you mean there's another seperate inductor between A and B? Apart from the one in the antenna?

Comment: I'm talking about an inductor on the circuit board or inside the module mounted to the circuit board. Post a schematic.